# As a beginner using Kivy 2.0 what steps do i take to compile my project(app) into play store

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Hello so I have been learning python and kivy for a year now and have finished coding my first app. It is a language learning app coded using the kivy framework.

I have been reading alot and watching tutorials but I haven't gotten the best response on what I need to do or what steps I post my app on playstore. Apparently buildozer doesn't work on windows.

As of now I have been using Kivy Launcher to test my apps.

For clarity my question is. Where do I start if I want to take my app (coded in Kivy) to playstore?

*I am using Kivy 2.0 and python 3.9.1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to use buildozer to create your .apk file. Apparently buildozer doesn't work on windows so you have to use a virtual machine to do so. After running a virtual machine (ubuntu) you have to install buildozer and all other requirements. You can check the details on [this page](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#targeting-android).
It's a long process and you will get a lot of errors while doing so. You can check some youtube tutorials like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcte8vcGMSU) (you won't need any server just use your virtual machine) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EupAeyL8zAo). You have to carefully provide requirements in buildozer.spec file. Your app will crash a lot of times. After a lot of efforts, you will finally be able to pack your first apk. Then you can do the things to publish your app on play store.

Comment: I disagree with the notion that "you will get a lot of errors", it certainly happens to some people, but if you follow instructions and install the dependencies as stated, it shouldn't be the case. Instead of indicating that their app will crash and they will need "a lot of efforts", it would be better to indicate *how* they could debug an app that crashes when ran on android (using buildozer android logcat or adb logcat). Also, using a VM is not he only solution on Windows, it's possible to use WSL on windows 10, buildozer works well there.